# OpenCL on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, c++, opencl

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 with a nvidia GTX 760 and I want to start working with OpenCL and C++. 
I installed the CUDA Toolkit 7.0 for Ubuntu 64Bit version and the current nvidia driver, but the function:

unsigned int platformIdCount = 0;

clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

returns always 0 in platformIdCount. How can I get access to my platforms? Are there any other files or packages to install?

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i have done it by myself.

I downloaded the current NVidia-CUDA-Toolkit. Then i shut down the X-server with:

> sudo service gdm stop

Then a blackscreen appeared where I pressed:

> Ctrl + Alt + F1

I just logged into my account, cd'd to the folder where the toolkit was and ran it:

> sudo sh "name of toolkit".run

After the installation i rebooted with

> sudo reboot

I hope this will help some other unexperienced Ubuntu users to get OpenCL running.